# Specify id for md-option for Angular Material

Tags: angular, selenium, angular-material2

In order to support automated testing with Selenium I need to specify ids for each md-option within an Angular Material md-select.  I want to start the id with zero with a prefix.  Example:  modelYear-0, modelYear-1

This does not work, the id is still id="md-option-275"

```
<md-select id="modelYearDropdown">
    <md-option *ngFor="let modelYear of modelYearList" [value]="modelYear.value" [id] = "modelYear.value" >
        {{ modelYear.viewValue }}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

I have also tried this which also does not work:

```
<md-select id="modelYearDropdown">
    <md-option *ngFor="let modelYear of modelYearList" [value]="modelYear.value" id = "{{index}}" >
        {{ modelYear.viewValue }}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: Can you add your ts code please ?